# How to use Rotativa with C# MVC authenticated ActionResult

Tags: c#, rotativa

I have an ASP MVC (version 4) webapp with form authentication. I am trying to use Rotativa version 1.6.4 to create a PDF from one of the Actions.
A PDF is downloaded but it is only one blank page, not the cshtml output expected. Any help would be great.

My code:

```
                //model is pre created
                return new ViewAsPdf("ActionName")
                {
                    FileName = "Report.pdf",
                    Model = model,                    
                    FormsAuthenticationCookieName = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName
                };
```

EDIT
I found that the Session I have is null when calling an Action via ActionAsPdf.
If I use this code for a View without any Viewbag or Session the PDF is fine:

```
        ActionAsPdf aap = new ActionAsPdf("PDFTest");
        aap.FileName = "a.pdf";
        return aap;
```

--EDIT: FOUND THE PROBLEM--
Simply dont use Session, for some reason all sessions are null in the Action to Rotativa is directing to.

And for those who need it, here is the docs: [doc](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)

Comment: Have you set the correct MIME type in the header? Alternatively, generate the PDF and create the response and response headers more explicitly (e.g., FileResult)

Comment: Hi, please see my edit: the Session I'm using throughout the app is null, any idea why? thanks.